# How to move from Viewcontroller to TabBarController without segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have such logic in my app:

[image]

I would like to move from ViewController to HomeScreen after 200 response from server, and in any other cases it will be done programmatically. I know about segue which can be attached to pressing button, but when I use segue and press login btn without text in fields I also move to Home Screen that is why I think that segue can't be used in such situation (I can be wrong), so I added id for Home Screen and added such code for pressing btn:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeScr") as? UITabBarController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

and when I press this button noting happens. What I did wrong and how to solve this problem?

Comment: could you please check the `self.navigationController`? maybe it is `null` / `nil`

Comment: @emrcftci, yes you are right, it is nil, I solved my problem with self.present(second, animated: true, completion: nil) but my second view is not in full screen :(

Comment: @Andrew, You need to configure the `modalPresentationStyle ` of `HomeSceen` to `fullScreen`, [more info in this link](https://zonneveld.dev/ios-13-viewcontroller-presentation-style-modalpresentationstyle/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller you push cannot be a Tabbarcontroller according to [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller).

```
The view controller to push onto the stack. This object cannot be a tab bar controller.
```

---

**Edit:**
As alternative this could be a solution:

```swift
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainApp") as! UITabBarController
nextViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: I solved my problem with self.present(second, animated: true, completion: nil) is it ok?

Comment: That's exactly what i did, but i'm unsure if this is the way to go as i only used it for PoC App.

Comment: does fullScreen not deprecated ?

Comment: It's just not the default anymore (since 2019) thus it has to be set specifically. You may or may not use it depending on what you wanna achieve i guess.

Answer (score 1):

In your appDelegate, add property:

```
final var window: UIWindow?
```

Open main like this in your Login view controller

```
func openMain() {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "mainApp") as! UITabBarController


    let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!
    window.rootViewController = nil
    window.rootViewController = nextViewController
        
    UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.4, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: nil, completion: nil)
}
```